# how to set widget form in to read only or disable it in yii version 1.x?

Tags: yii

I have this piece of code in my view file

```
            <div>
                <div class="column span-4"><?php echo $form->labelEx($model, "name"); ?></div>
                <div class="column span-flexible">
                    <?php echo $this->module->createWidget($form, $model,"name"); ?>
                    <ul class="errorlist"><li><?php echo $form->error($model, "name"); ?></li></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

how to make it as read only? or disable it?
I have tried already these methods

```
<?php echo $this->module->createWidget($form, $model,"name",array('htmlOptions' => array('readonly'=>'readonly')); ?>
```

OR

```
<?php echo $this->module->createWidget($form, $model,"name",array('htmlOptions'=>array('readOnly' => 'readOnly')); ?>
```

OR

```
<?php echo $this->module->createWidget($form, $model,"name",array('htmlOptions'=>array('readonly'=>true)); ?>
```

None of those worked. what's the solution to fix this in order to make it as read only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to write script for that input

```
 document.getElementById("name").readOnly = true;
```

Comment: you mean there's no yii 1.x way to make it read only ? , so javascript is the only way?

Comment: <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="Firstname"  readonly/>

Comment: try that may be you get solution that you need i am not sure bt it might work

Comment: that's plain html...i'm using a php framework , therefore, the input form is made dynamically on the fly

Comment: you can convert input to html right. so just convert it set required field. you just have to copy that code from ur inspect and set in <?php echo "your copy code"?>

Comment: and if you don't want to convert input to html then define rule for that field in model as required  =====                                                                      
public function rules() {
    return array(
        array('phone', 'required'),
    );
}

Comment: i can do a plain html, a plain php thing to generate a simple form. the problem is, i must follow the standard procedure in creating form..to avoid ugly stuffs in view files

Comment: then you have to define rule for required field in model as required